# Launch Google Map, but return with Activity restarted

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

In my app, I launch Google Map from a Fragment as following:

```
mBtnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
...   
    String uri = String.format(locale, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));    
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
...
```

When I press the back button, my app resumes but the Activity is restarted. I want it come back to the Fragment where the Google Map startActivity() is invoked.

Did I do something out of ordinary that makes the Activity restart?
How to achieve my purpose?

Comment: do u add "android:launchMode="singleTop"" in yr manidest file?

Comment: Add some logging to your `Activity`, especially `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onDestroy()` and see which of the lifecycle methods are actually being called and when. The behaviour you've described is strange and non-standard. It may be that the device has low memory and needs to kill your app's process in order to start the Google Maps process. In that case your `Activity` will be restarted. But add logging and check if that is really what is happening.

Comment: None of other suggestion works for me, I will try your suggestion later.  For now, I solved the problem by simply using startActivityResult to start the Google Map activity.  Don't know why ... but workaround it for now.  If you have any theory, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

```
    try{
    String uri = String.format(locale, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent);
    }catch(Exception e){
    // ActivityNotFoundException
    }
```

Comment: And how is this differnt from OP's original code? What have you done differently here?